# How to embed generic file media entities?

Tags: 8, files, media

I'm using modules [Media entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity) and [Entity embed](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_embed) and [Entity Browser](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_browser), which all work fine for images and video.

Now I'd like to use the Media framework to also manage some PDF and other non-image documents and embed them into my nodes and other places. Uploading and managing generic documents works – I've tried both the "Generic file" provider, as well as the contributed "Media entity document" module.

But embedding is a nightmare. The embed dialog will let me display generic file media entities as either ID, title or thumbnail and optionally link to the media entity's page. All of this is useless to me. I don't want to allow visitors to access media pages, I'd like a simple link to the (downloadable) file instead.

Can someone tell me how to embed and make use of generic file media?

Comment: There is a module for this https://www.drupal.org/project/medf

Comment: Although it has a specific use case. Media URIs need a download path to force the browser to download the file. This does not yet exist, to my knowledge.

Comment: I'm not worried about download vs. display in browser. It's just I don't see a decent way to render an embedded PDF (for example) document. The link that is provided by the Embed module leads to the media page, not to the actual document file's URL.

Comment: You'd likely have to build a handler then, if one does not already exist. This is due to media not knowing about your file - it only represents a media object (which could have many file/image fields on it).

Comment: What do mean by 'handler'?